# How to sync files on Windows 7 so Dropbox notices the changes

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, mklink

I want a file on my hard drive in Windows 7 to sync to my public dropbox folder.

I can do this with:

```
mklink /H "c:\dropbox\Public\test.txt" "c:\data\test.txt"
```

And the first time after I do this, the file `c:\dropbox\Public\test.txt` is indeed created, and is available online via `http://dl.dropbox.com/u/.../test.txt`.

And when I update the file `c:\data\test.txt` then indeed the file `c:\dropbox\Public\test.txt` reflects the changes, **however**: `http://dl.dropbox.com/u/.../test.txt` **does not** reflect the changes since DropBox somehow doesn't get the information that that file was changed.

**What is a workaround or another solution to this so that any changes in the original file is also reflected in the dropbox URL link?**

Answer (score 4):

I'm using a folder symlink instead, and putting my files under that symlinked folder, and do not experience your problem so far, I think its easier than put a symlinked file(s) to a dropbox folder

Just a suggestion, use mklink /D to symlink a folder :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure the "canonical" version of the file is in Dropbox's folder:

- First move the original "real" file to your Dropbox folder
- Then in the folder the file used to be, create a (hard?) link that points to the file that was just moved to Dropbox.

reference: [Watch any folder/junction/symbolic links bug](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=20980)

I do this to synchronize my vim settings.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox has an official response about this at: https://www.dropbox.com/help/145

In short, Dropbox only sees changes in linked files/junctions each time Dropbox client opens/restarts.

If you want changes to reflect immediately, you have to put your ORIGINAL files INSIDE Dropbox folder, and make a link outside pointing to THAT file/folder.

Examples:

- C:/Dropbox/MyFolder is a link to D:/MyFolder --> Changes will sync after Dropbox restart.
- D:/MyFolder is a link to C:/Dropbox/MyFolder --> Changes will be synced immediately.

That's an issue to me, since I need two HDs to store my data, but that's how it works.